# Why is S3PutEvent empty for this Go AWS Lambda?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a very basic Go lambda running in AWS:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, event events.S3Event) {
    fmt.Printf("%+v", event)
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}
```

With `go.mod`

```
module xxx

go 1.18

require github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go v1.32.1
```

This lambda is triggered by PUT on S3, using an SQS queue. The events arrive at the lambda, but when I upload a file to S3, the logs print an empty event:

```
{Records:[{EventVersion: EventSource:aws:sqs AWSRegion:eu-central-1 EventTime:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC EventName: PrincipalID:{PrincipalID:} RequestParameters:{SourceIPAddress:} ResponseElements:map[] S3:{SchemaVersion: ConfigurationID: Bucket:{Name: OwnerIdentity:{PrincipalID:} Arn:} Object:{Key: Size:0 URLDecodedKey: VersionID: ETag: Sequencer:}}}]}
```

Now when I go in the AWS lambda console and click Test Event using the provided S3 PUT example, the event is printed correctly, including the example values.

I'm thinking that this might be because the event from SQS is in a different format than expected? It's not a test event, I tried this as well.

How can I see which event is being passed to my lambda?

Answer (score 2):

Ah. Turns out it should be a `SQSEvent`, which wraps the `S3Event`.